# YT Content Owners Video Report NOT updating - content_owner_video_metadata_a2

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Every day, we download a youtube content owner video report for two different content owners.  We connect to the API and pull data from the following endpoint:  content_owner_video_metadata_a2.  Since November 17th, 2022, we have NOT been able to pull any new data for this report.  In fact, the API returns no data at all.  My business users are able to see this data in the front-end GUI for content owners and on their end, it also shows that the data has not been updated since the 17th.  Is there an issue that we should know about?  How can we get this data to be updated??  Please let me know if you need any other details to help you understand my issue.  Thanks!

I was expecting the API to return data, which I then download into a CSV file.  No data is being returned and so no file is being created.

Comment: has this issue been resolved for you?

Comment: Yes!  We reached out to YouTube Developer Relations and they admitted there was an issue and they eventually resolved it.  Thanks!