# YouTube Content Owner video metadata report - no reports for reporting job

Tags: google-bigquery, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm using a BigQuery Data Transfer to load YouTube Content Owner data into BigQuery. The transfers run daily. Even though transfers have been successful, there is no new data arriving for content owner video metadata reports (p_content_owner_video_metadata_a2). Logs are the following:

> No reports for reporting job with name [Automatically created content_owner_video_metadata_a2 job] and id [id_here]

The last time data was returned was 15.11.2022. For some reason YouTube API documentation doesn't include metadata reports at all. Is it normal that data is returned so rarely, and if not what could be the reason for no data being returned in the last 2 weeks?

I tried scheduling backfills for dates after 15.11.2022 thinking perhaps it was a one-time thing, but still no reports are being returned.

Comment: Other folks, including me, are experiencing the same issue. See other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601848/yt-content-owners-video-report-not-updating-content-owner-video-metadata-a2)